# analogue of rollback in neo4j via php

Tags: php, neo4j

Do neo4jphp have any analogue of savepoint and rollback like in postgresql? I need to rollback all changes in transaction in php script if some actions throw exception. I use neo4jphp library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the batch API to get the equivalent of a transaction via REST. Read more about how it works here: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-batch-ops.html#rest-api-execute-multiple-operations-in-batch

Check out some of the batch examples from neo4jphp: https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/blob/master/examples/batch_benchmarks.php

Comment: Yes, i'm already reading about batch, but don't think that it's good choice. It's not thread safe and not recommended to use but for importing of large amount of data .

Comment: I think you might be confused between the batch REST API and the batch inserter. As far as I know it executes a batch REST command in a single transaction, which should be thread safe.

Comment: Another option is to execute a single Cypher command with all of your statements in it, if possible.

Comment: If you say REST batch is thread safe and can't corrupt database file — this is what i need. Thanks.

Comment: Wes is right. The only way to commit multiple statements atomically over REST is with a batch. Any commands in the batch are wrapped in a transaction on the server.